# Kotlin constructor properties val can't be used in the class

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor

Following works

```
class PagerAdapter(var tabCount: Int, fm: FragmentManager?) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Fragment { 
        return when (p0) {
            0 -> TabFragment1()
            1 -> TabFragment2()
            2 -> TabFragment3()
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid color param value")
        }
    }
    override fun getCount() = tabCount
}
```

and this doesn't (Unresolved reference :tabCount)

```
class PagerAdapter(tabCount: Int, fm: FragmentManager?) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Fragment { 
        return when (p0) {
            0 -> TabFragment1()
            1 -> TabFragment2()
            2 -> TabFragment3()
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid color param value")
        }
    }
    override fun getCount() = tabCount
}
```

I am new to Kotlin and just confused why can't you use the val properties in the class itself. Can someone please explain? Thanks

Comment: Btw, if I create a new variable in the class the second code works too:  val tc = tabCount and use tc in getCount.

Comment: Did you mean to have `val tabCount: Int` in your second example? Omitting `var` and `val` means you're specifying a constructor parameter, but it's not stored as a property.

Comment: @apemanzilla thanks. I was wrong. I thought all constructor arguments are properties and you don't need to add val it's default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second doesn't work as you are not declaring any properties for the class.
Just mentioning them in the brackets does not make them properties, rather it can be compared as if they were just parameters of a constructor.

You either want to use `var` or `val`... you can make them `private` if you like.

Check also [Kotlins reference about classes and inheritance, more specifically the constructor chapter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors):

> In fact, for declaring properties and initializing them from the primary constructor, Kotlin has a concise syntax:
>
> ```
> class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, var age: Int) { ... }
> ```
>
> Much the same way as regular properties, the properties declared in the primary constructor can be mutable `var` or read-only `val`.

Comment: It's a bit confusing but make sense now. Thank you

Comment: if you have not done so already, I can only recommend to read that chapter about the constructors... e.g. sooner or later you will need the secondary ones... and it also shows how to assign constructor parameter to existing properties, which aren't part of the constructor itself...

Answer (score 1):

`tabCount` and `fm` in `class PagerAdapter(tabCount: Int, fm: FragmentManager?)` are just constructor parameters.
They are not members of the class.

It is like

```
class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    PagerAdapter(int tabCount, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm)
    }
    ...
}
```

in Java.

You have to specify they are class fields by adding `val` in front of them.

```
class PagerAdapter(val tabCount: Int, val fm: FragmentManager?) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Fragment { 
        return when (p0) {
            0 -> TabFragment1()
            1 -> TabFragment2()
            2 -> TabFragment3()
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid color param value")
        }
    }
    override fun getCount() = tabCount
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
class PagerAdapter(var tabCount: Int) : SomeBase() {
    override fun getCount() = tabCount
}
```

since when you specify `var` or `val` to primary constructor parameter, the parameter becomes property of the class.

---

But when you **do not** specify the parameter with `var` or `val`, it is not stored. However, you can still use this value inside `init` block:

```
class PagerAdapter(tabCount: Int) {
    init {
        Log.d("$tabCount")
    }
}
```

or to initialize some custom property:

```
class PagerAdapter(tabCount: Int) {
    val tabCountTenTimes: Int = tabCount * 10
}
```

Though you can't use such a parameter in method like you have tried - you need a property for this.